# How to control the squash of a geo rigged with bendy bones?

Tags: bones

There is a way to control the squash over a model rigged on a bendy bone?
I whant to enphatize the volume when squashed, of course i know the possibility to use a blend shape with driven key, but to have a control over how much the bendy bones squash the mesh would be great!
Thanks to all,
Carlo

Comment: Please provide examples and screenshots